# apktool compile error No resource found that matches the given name (at 'pointDrawable' with value '@ android:drawable/APKTOOL_DUMMY_0302'

Tags: android, string, compilation, apk, apktool

i am trying to add values-ru folders to SystemUI.apk (android),in order to add russian language to my ROM UI. All went fine with framework-res.apk and settings.apk, but when i try to re-compile the SystemUI.apk, it does say like this: (could not paste the code here and put it to pastebin -> [PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/ZxCmbQf9)

i,ve installed, decompiled it right, why is it doing this?

Answer (score 0):

i will answer my own question. the problem is that i didnt decompile the apk in the right way. i supposed to load resources from mediatek-res.apk and framework-res.apk by command `apktool if framework-res.apk`, using apktool